# Can we legally monetize the translation of videos on our service using YouTube API?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, youtube

The question arose whether we would violate API policy when creating a new service ( 7th and 9th point in the link https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies)

We are a team of developers and our startup's model is the following:

We want to use YouTube Player API to display videos from various channels on our website and then going to overlay an audio track with video's translation made by us (on the website it looks like audio from separate player is broadcasted on the same page with API video player), i.e. using the YouTube Player API to mute the original audio and play the audio track of its translation from our site (html audio tag).

We would like to clarify:

1. Does this violate the policy if we gonna monetize the service?
2. If yes, will it still be a violation if the creators of the original video agree that we will overlay translation of their video on our site?

Or if you know whom to contact regarding that, please feel free to share

Huge thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

### YouTube offers posters a choice of 2 [licences](https://filmora.wondershare.com/youtube-video-editing/standard-youtube-license-vs-cc.html)

**Standard YouTube Licence**

This allows YouTube to broadcast and others to link to that broadcast. You can’t make derivative works which is what your translation app does.

**Creative Commons Licence**

Users who choose this option allow deriving works if you comply with the licence.